# Expose php templating engine to user?

Tags: php, security, templates, twig

I want to build a report builder into a web app of mine. The user collects data through other parts of the site, and then should be able to generate "reports" in which he/she can use said data in a document-style fashion. I want the user to be able to use basic math functionality, get/set their own variables, etc. I figure why reinvent the wheel? If I were to allow the user to write the report with something like [Twig Template Engine](http://www.twig-project.org/) and only enable certain extensions for them to use, does this seem reasonably secure? Twig templates already remove any php found in the markup, and there aren't too many powerful functions that you can use, other than basic string alterations, etc. Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twig has a fairly powerful [sandbox extension](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/api.html#sandbox-extension) that does exactly what you're describing. With a sufficiently stringent security policy, I can't see any problems here.

Comment: How widely used is this?  https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/search?q=sandbox suggests it's been around for the better part of a year, but has anyone made a concerted effort to attack Twig's sandbox?  Are there best practices for policy writers?

Comment: I know that the entire Symfony2 codebase (in which Twig is used as the default templating engine) was subject to [a security audit](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-2-0) by SektionEins (last bullet point under "The Code"), but whether Twig in general and the sandbox extension specifically were tested, I couldn't say. As far as best practices, I sincerely doubt anything like that has surfaced yet, aside from the default policy provided.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I can't find anything on the scope or ground rules for the audit.  To the OP, I'd ask Symfony whether they rely on the sandbox for anything before I'd rely on it to protect anything of value.  When I've written sandboxes, the first group of attackers has always found something.

Comment: In addition to talking to the creators, you might also put the extension through the paces yourself, see if you can get anything to break with an (un?)reasonable use case from your userbase.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I will look into contacting Symfony, and take a crack at the sandbox myself.

Answer (score 1):

If twig does what you need, why not? It's pretty well done, has a sandbox mode and can compile the templates. In the opposite, offering PHP from PHP is hard to divide, so using some template sounds not bad to me.